# Get the first 2 elements of an array in an aggregation query in MongoDB 3.0

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Just before anyone proposes I use `$slice` in my aggregation query, I'm using mongolab as my backend engine and it doesn't support mongo 3.2, it only supports up to 3.0, so I cannot use `$slice`.

I'm trying to get the first two commentor's names from an array of commentors.

The dataset looks like this after completing some aggregation magic:

```
{ "_id" : "e", "commentor" : [ "John", "Bethany", "Mary", "Peter", "Mike", "Simon" ]}
{ "_id" : "f", "commentor" : [ "Sam", "Jan", "George", "Fred", "Greg", "Paul", "Ben" ]}
```

In each of these posts, I have a list of commentors.

The idea is to extract only the first 2 commentors and then do a `$size` of the array so that I can generate an activity feed with just the relevant info. For example, for post id = `e`, I want the activity feed to say:

```
John, Bethany and 4 other people commented on post e.
```

I can easily do an aggregation query for the $first commentor by saying:

```
group2 = {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$_id",
        "commentor" : {
            "$first" : "$commentor"
        }
    }
}
```

In which case my activity feed would display:

```
John and 5 other people commented on post e.
```

But I would like my result to be this instead:

```
John, Bethany and 4 other people commented on post e.
```

Is there anyway to do this on mongo 3.0?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this with the aggregation framework in 3.0. If this the the last stage in the pipeline, then you can use client-side processing to retrieve the first two elements in the array.

Comment: I know you can do that but just now you have 1000 comments on a post, it would just take too long to download the doc and the client would run out of memory.

Comment: You can `$unwind` the array and `$limit` the result but that also will be expensive because of how `$unwind` works. But I can tell exactly what the best option here since I don't have access to your pipeline.

Comment: I don't think $unwind and $limit would work if there are multiple posts within my social network. I need to limit it by 2 for post e and 2 for post f  separately and i do not want the limit to be applied for all the posts in totality.

Comment: That is why I didn't post it as answer in  the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Using the $match, $project, $unwind, $limit and $group in the Aggregate Pipeline we can acheive it.

Below is the query which does the magic.

```
db.stackoverflow1.aggregate([
   {$match : { "_id": "e"  }},  // Pass the value of post you want to retrieve, in this query we are passing "e" 
   {$project: {commentor: 1, numberOfCommentors: { $size: "$commentor" }}},
   {$unwind: "$commentor"}, 
   {$limit : 2 },
   {$group : {"_id":{_id:"$_id", numberOfCommentors:"$numberOfCommentors"}, 
    myArr:{$push: {commentor :"$commentor"}} 
    }}   
 ])
```

**How it works**
First query in the pipeline is $match, which helps us in reducing our results

```
 db.stackoverflow1.aggregate([ {$match : { "_id": "e"  }} ])
```

This section will yield us

```
{ "_id" : "e", "commentor" : [ "John", "Bethany", "Mary", "Peter", "Mike", "Simon" ] }
```

Now we have the desired record, but we have to work towards showing 2 commentor names and count of commentors

$project is the next section in our aggregation pipeline, with this we projected the commentors and their count to the next stage.

Our query with $project

```
db.stackoverflow1.aggregate([ {$match : { "_id": "e"  }},
{$project: {commentor: 1, numberOfCommentors: { $size: "$commentor" }}} ])
```

After executing this query our result set will be

```
{ "_id" : "e", "commentor" : [ "John", "Bethany", "Mary", "Peter", "Mike", "Simon" ], "numberOfCommentors" : 6 }
```

We just added the number of commentors to our desired result in the previous query and projected it to the next stage in the pipeline.

Now we need to unwind our commentors array to take only two commentors

Our query with $unwind

```
 db.stackoverflow1.aggregate([
  {$match : { "_id": "e"  }},
  {$project: {commentor: 1, numberOfCommentors: { $size: "$commentor" }}},
  {$unwind: "$commentor"}
 ])
```

Now our result will be as shown below after executing our query $unwind

```
{ "_id" : "e", "commentor" : "John", "numberOfCommentors" : 6 }
{ "_id" : "e", "commentor" : "Bethany", "numberOfCommentors" : 6 }
{ "_id" : "e", "commentor" : "Mary", "numberOfCommentors" : 6 }
{ "_id" : "e", "commentor" : "Peter", "numberOfCommentors" : 6 }
{ "_id" : "e", "commentor" : "Mike", "numberOfCommentors" : 6 }
{ "_id" : "e", "commentor" : "Simon", "numberOfCommentors" : 6 }
```

We unwinded the commentors array and we are also brought in the count of commentors, the rest is to limit the count to 2 and group it, that is our final query and the result after executing our final query is

```
{ "_id" : { "_id" : "e", "numberOfCommentors" : 6 }, "myArr" : [ { "commentor" : "John" }, { "commentor" : "Bethany" } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but i don't think it will really work if there is more than 1 post like in my example, I have post e and post f. You are limiting the count of post e to 2 but if you have both post e and post f, this will not work.

Comment: we are limiting the number of commentors on post e to 2, but not restricting on posts. If we want more posts to be handled, then please modify the $match section. The query posted above will bring the desired result as :

       "John, Bethany and 4 other people commented on post e ".          To obtain the count you should be subtracting 2 from the numberOfCommentors

Comment: @Simon - Added comment on the query.